# Joomla url redirect to another domain

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I have created 5 menu items with a menu from Joomla admin panel. Out of 5, 4 menu item should be redirected to the same domain and the 5th one should redirect to another domain url.

How to do that in Joomla admin panel? I am totally new to Joomla. The correct guidance is appreciable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use External Link while Menu creation. So you need to follow below steps.

1. Go to Menu Manager.
2. Select New Menu.
3. Now you will see the `Menu Item Type` field , Click on `Select` Button.
4. Here You need to choose Click on `System Link`.
5. Now it will open this options, i.e Menu Heading, Menu Item Alias, Separator, URL.
6. Choose `URL` option.
7. Now you need to give external link in the field `Link` textbox.

Hope it will solve your problem :)

Comment: I did it but it redirects to mycurrrentdomain/#undefined

Comment: What URL you entered there ?